# Xcode XIB: how to implement a ScrollView or PageControl to swipe sub-views?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I'm building a typical Xcode 6 iOS app.

My goal is:

- A screen that has an sub-area that can be swiped to change the content.
- For example, the home screen has a logo image, a middle area that I want to be swipeable, and a bottom button.
- When the user swipes (or taps) the middle area, the area shows the next (or previous) information, which is a typical UIImage and UILabel caption.
- The rest of the screen stays the same, i.e. there is no navigation change.

The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/SixArm/9b5641accf56ff936e65). It use the recommendations from the StackOverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391048/xcode-how-do-i-change-uipagecontrol-value-with-swipe-gesture).

**My question: how can I implement the code below better, while still using an XIB?**

My current implementation does work, and uses this approach...

A typical Swift `Demo.swift` file that is a UIViewController that has:

- the page index, min, and max
- outlets for the PageControl, UIImageView, and UILabel
- actions for the page control change, and the image swipe or tap

A typical `Demo.xib` file that has:

- a typical UIViewController for the entire screen
- a UIImageView and UILabel for the changeable image and caption text
- a PageControl to indicate what tutorial page the user is viewing

I am seeking better ways to accomplish this; I've read many of Xcode tutorials and so far none seem definitive for Xcode 6, XIBs, and Swift.

Here are some implementations that I've researched that seem promising...

Is there a way to implement a subview area in the XIB?

- For example, can Xocde show the XIB with a rectangular area that is intended for the changeable content?

Is there an idiomatic way to write the code for changeable content?

- For example, by using a ScrollView, perhaps that contains a UIPageViewController?

Is there a way to make a PageControl XIB object large enough to cover the entire UIImageView and UILabel, so I can skip making the UIImageView respond to gestures.

- In my Xcode, the PageControl seems to have an uneditable height that is always 37.

The bounty will be for expert advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a UIPageViewController swipe-able you should implement the `UIPageViewControllerDataSource` protocol and provide a view controller for the `pageViewController(pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController) -> UIViewController?` and the `...viewControllerAfterViewController)` methods.

Provide a custom view controller for each page that presents an image and label and takes them as properties so you can provide them from the PageViewController.

My trick it to create a method that instantiates a new view controller in these methods:

```
// MARK:- UIPageViewControllerDataSource

extension MyPageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

  func viewControllerWithIndex(var index: Int) -> UIViewController! {
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as! MyViewController // This VC has to be in the storyboard, otherwise just use MyVC()

    // Adjust the index to be cyclical, not required
    if let count = data?.endIndex {
      if count == 1 && index != 0 { return nil }
      if index < 0 { index += count }
      index %= count
    }

    viewController.view.tag = index
    viewController.record = data?[index]

    return viewController
  }

  func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfterViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let index = viewController.view?.tag ?? 0
    return viewControllerWithIndex(index + 1)
  }

  func pageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBeforeViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let index = viewController.view?.tag ?? 0
    return viewControllerWithIndex(index - 1)
  }

  func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return countAndSetupPageControl()
  }

  func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
    return viewController?.view.tag ?? 0
  }
}
```

Now for the "sub-area" you will need to implement a `ChildViewController`. If you're using storyboards you can just drag a `Container View` and put `PageViewController` in the embedded view controller, otherwise you need to add the `PageViewController.view` as a subview and set the `frame` to the middle.

You can find more info in the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html)  but basically you MUST call these methods:

```
addChildViewController(pageViewController)
view.addSubView(pageViewController.view)
pageViewController.view.frame = ... // This is your "sub-area"
pageViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: Thank you! I especially like the way you instantiate the view controller as you need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a height constraint to PageControl you can set it's height to whatever you want.

I don't see a problem with your current implementation. Changing it to use a PageViewController would be quite more work.

If I were you I would add an animation in pageUpdate function so the image would fade in or slide in...

It would only make sense to use a PageViewController if you want to be able to scroll to the next page (as in content moving in the same time your finger is moving onscreen). And you can use a PageViewController or a CollectionView with paging enabled.